# Postfix header_checks replace multiple occurrences inside References header

Tags: regex, pcre, postfix-mta, mta

In postfix header_checks can be used to replace any header. This works for example perfectly for the Message-Id header.

Example:

```
/Message-Id:\s+<(.*?)@domain-a.com>/ REPLACE Message-Id: <$1@domain-b.com>
```

Any mail which is processed by postfix will be checked for the Header:

```
Message-Id: <example@domain-a.com>
```

and gets replaced with:

```
Message-Id: <example@domain-b.com>
```

How does this work with References Header?

Example Header:

```
References: <mail-1@domain-a.com> <mail-2@domain-a.com> <mail-3@domain-a.com>
```

---

**Goal:**

Replace any (1 - n) occurrence of domain-a.com with domain-b.com in this References header.

Try 1:

```
#/References:\s+<(.*?)@domain-a.com>/ REPLACE References: <$1@domain-b.com>
```

(works only with first occurence)

Try 2:

```
#/<.*?@(domain-a.com)>/ REPLACE domain-b.com
```

Does not work because header_checks need a valid Header name for the REPLACE command.

Can this replace achived with postfix native header_checks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use
`(^References:|\G(?!\A)).*?@\Kdomain-a\.com`
with substitution `domain-b.com`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qpvmus/1)

Comment: Thank you very much! The regex is exactly what I'm searching for. Do you also know how the replacement works? 


/expression/ REPLACE References: <${n}@domain-b.com>

will result in bad syntax.